# Restarting an optimisation with Pymoo

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

I'm trying to restart an optimisation in pymoo.

I have a problem defined as:

```
class myOptProb(Problem):
    """my body goes here"""

algorithm = NSGA2(pop_size=24)  

problem = myOptProblem(opt_obj=dp_ptr,
                       nvars=7,
                       nobj=4,
                       nconstr=0,
                       lb=0.3 * np.ones(7),
                       ub=0.7 * np.ones(7),
                       parallelization=('threads', cpu_count(),))

res = minimize(problem,
               algorithm,
               ('n_gen', 100),
               seed=1,
               verbose=True)
```

During the optimisation I write the design vectors and results to a .csv file. An example of design_vectors.csv is:

```
5.000000000000000000e+00, 4.079711567060104183e-01, 6.583544872784267143e-01, 4.712364759485179189e-01, 6.859360188593541796e-01, 5.653765991273791425e-01, 5.486782880836487131e-01, 5.275405748345924906e-01,
7.000000000000000000e+00, 5.211287914743063521e-01, 6.368123569438421949e-01, 3.496693260479644128e-01, 4.116734716044557763e-01, 5.343037085833151068e-01, 6.878382993278697732e-01, 5.244120877022839800e-01, 
9.000000000000000000e+00, 5.425317846613321171e-01, 5.275405748345924906e-01, 4.269449637288642574e-01, 6.954464617649794844e-01, 5.318980876983187001e-01, 4.520564690494201510e-01, 5.203792876471586837e-01, 
1.100000000000000000e+01, 4.579502451694219545e-01, 6.853050113762846340e-01, 3.695822666721857441e-01, 3.505318077758549089e-01, 3.540316632186925050e-01, 5.022648662707586142e-01, 3.086099221096791911e-01, 
3.000000000000000000e+00, 4.121775968257620493e-01, 6.157117313805953174e-01, 3.412904026310568106e-01, 4.791574104703620329e-01, 6.634382012372381787e-01, 4.174456593494717538e-01, 4.151101354345394512e-01,
```

The results.csv is:

```
5.000000000000000000e+00, 1.000000000000000000e+05, 1.000000000000000000e+05, 1.000000000000000000e+05, 1.000000000000000000e+05, 
7.000000000000000000e+00, 1.041682833582066703e+00, 3.481167125962069189e-03, -5.235115318709097909e-02, 4.634480813876099177e-03, 
9.000000000000000000e+00, 1.067730307802263967e+00, 2.194702810002167534e-02, -3.195892023664552717e-01, 1.841232582360878426e-03, 
1.100000000000000000e+01, 8.986880344052742275e-01, 2.969022150977750681e-03, -4.346692726475211849e-02, 4.995468429444801205e-03, 
3.000000000000000000e+00, 9.638770499257821589e-01, 1.859596479928402393e-02, -2.723230073142696162e-01, 1.600910928983005632e-03,
```

The first column is the index of the design vector - because I thread asynchronously, I specify the indices.

I see that it should be possible to restart the optimisation via the sampling parameter for `pymoo.algorithms.nsga2.NSGA2` but I couldn't find a working example. The documentation for both population and individuals is also not clear. So how can I restart a simulation with the previous results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can initialize the algorithm object with a population instead of doing it randomly.

I have written a small tutorial for a biased initialization:
https://pymoo.org/customization/initialization.html

Because in your case the data already exists, in a CSV or in-memory file, you might want to create a dummy problem (I have called it `Constant` in my example) to set the attributes in the `Population` object. (In the population `X`, `F`, `G`, `CV` and `feasible` needs to be set). Another way would be setting the attributes directly...

The biased initialization with a dummy problem is shown below. If you already use pymoo to store the csv files, you can also just `np.save` the `Population` object directly and load it. Then all intermediate steps are not necessary.

I am planning to improve checkpoint implementation in the future. So if you have some more feedback and use case which are not possible yet please let me know.

```
import numpy as np

from pymoo.algorithms.nsga2 import NSGA2
from pymoo.algorithms.so_genetic_algorithm import GA
from pymoo.factory import get_problem, G1, Problem
from pymoo.model.evaluator import Evaluator
from pymoo.model.population import Population
from pymoo.optimize import minimize


class YourProblem(Problem):

    def __init__(self, n_var=10):
        super().__init__(n_var=n_var, n_obj=1, n_constr=0, xl=-0, xu=1, type_var=np.double)

    def _evaluate(self, x, out, *args, **kwargs):
        out["F"] = np.sum(np.square(x - 0.5), axis=1)


problem = YourProblem()

# create initial data and set to the population object - for your this is your file
N = 300
X = np.random.random((N, problem.n_var))
F = np.random.random((N, problem.n_obj))
G = np.random.random((N, problem.n_constr))


class Constant(YourProblem):

    def _evaluate(self, x, out, *args, **kwargs):
        out["F"] = F
        out["G"] = G


pop = Population().new("X", X)
Evaluator().eval(Constant(), pop)

algorithm = GA(pop_size=100, sampling=pop)

minimize(problem,
         algorithm,
         ('n_gen', 10),
         seed=1,
         verbose=True)
```