# Restarted solution with Pymoo fails

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I've restarted a solution in Pymoo, however, the optimisation run breaks when the number of objectives is greater than 1 and search is with NSGA2. See also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63456711/4782513).

```
import numpy as np

from pymoo.algorithms.nsga2 import NSGA2
from pymoo.algorithms.so_genetic_algorithm import GA
from pymoo.factory import get_problem, G1, Problem
from pymoo.model.evaluator import Evaluator
from pymoo.model.population import Population
from pymoo.optimize import minimize


class YourProblem(Problem):

    def __init__(self, n_var=10):
        super().__init__(n_var=n_var, n_obj=3, n_constr=0, xl=-0, xu=1, type_var=np.double)

    def _evaluate(self, x, out, *args, **kwargs):
        out["F"] = np.sum(np.square(x - 0.5), axis=1)


problem = YourProblem()

# create initial data and set to the population object - for your this is your file
N = 300
X = np.random.random((N, problem.n_var))
F = np.random.random((N, problem.n_obj))
G = np.random.random((N, problem.n_constr))


class Constant(YourProblem):

    def _evaluate(self, x, out, *args, **kwargs):
        out["F"] = F
        out["G"] = G


pop = Population().new("X", X)
Evaluator().eval(Constant(), pop)

algorithm = NSGA2(pop_size=100, sampling=pop)

minimize(problem,
         algorithm,
         ('n_gen', 10),
         seed=1,
         verbose=True)
```

When run the code raises the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "restart_opt.py", line 45, in <module>
    verbose=True)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymoo/optimize.py", line 76, in minimize
    res = algorithm.solve()
  File "/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymoo/model/algorithm.py", line 208, in solve
    self._solve(self.problem)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymoo/model/algorithm.py", line 289, in _solve
    self.next()
  File "/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymoo/model/algorithm.py", line 260, in next
    self._next()
  File "/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymoo/algorithms/genetic_algorithm.py", line 105, in _next
    self.pop = self.survival.do(self.problem, self.pop, self.pop_size, algorithm=self)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymoo/model/survival.py", line 49, in do
    survivors = self._do(problem, pop, n_survive, **kwargs)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymoo/algorithms/nsga2.py", line 128, in _do
    F = pop.get("F").astype(np.float, copy=False)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, the number of objectives is not really greater than one. The `_evaluate` needs to assign a NumPy matrix to `out["F"]` with three columns where each column represents one objective.

I have converted your example to a **bi-objective** problem. Please see the code below (and note that for three or more objectives NSGA-III is known to perform better than NSGA-II):

```
import numpy as np

from pymoo.algorithms.nsga2 import NSGA2
from pymoo.factory import Problem
from pymoo.model.evaluator import Evaluator
from pymoo.model.population import Population
from pymoo.optimize import minimize


class YourProblem(Problem):

    def __init__(self, n_var=10):
        super().__init__(n_var=n_var, n_obj=2, n_constr=0, xl=-0, xu=1, type_var=np.double)

    def _evaluate(self, x, out, *args, **kwargs):
        f1 = np.sum(np.square(x - 0.25), axis=1)
        f2 = np.sum(np.square(x - 0.75), axis=1)
        out["F"] = np.column_stack([f1, f2])


problem = YourProblem()

# create initial data and set to the population object - for your this is your file
N = 300
X = np.random.random((N, problem.n_var))
F, G = YourProblem().evaluate(X, return_values_of=["F", "G"])


class Constant(YourProblem):

    def _evaluate(self, x, out, *args, **kwargs):
        out["F"] = F
        out["G"] = G


pop = Population().new("X", X)
Evaluator().eval(Constant(), pop)

algorithm = NSGA2(pop_size=100, sampling=pop)

minimize(problem,
         algorithm,
         ('n_gen', 10),
         seed=1,
         verbose=True)
```